# How ref modifier is works for value and refernce types??Can someone explain thoroughly?

Tags: c#, .net

i have read about  this in the books Troelsen and Schildt .And now i am confused.Their opinion in this question is different.Schildt explains that in the case when you pass for instance integer type through ref the function get copy of adress that shows where variable is in the heap.Troelsen explains that function get oriignal copy....and if it is possible i woul dlike to hear abot the case when refrenece type has passed through ref...

Comment: See http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html - although my guess is that you've misread Troelsen.

Comment: Thanks a lot .Mr Skeet

Comment: @JonSkeet's article is all you need to know, look no further.

Answer (score 3):

When you pass a variable as an argument to a method using `ref`, you're not just passing the argument - you're giving that method control of the variable itself. (That's why you can only pass variables using `ref`, not properties.)

If I have a variable

```
var x = 1;
```

and I pass it to a method *without* `ref`

```
void DoSomethingWith(int arg)
{
    arg++;
}

DoSomethingWith(x);
```

Then that method, `DoSomethingWith` can do anything it wants with `arg`. But for the calling method, `x` will still equal 1.

But if I pass it using `ref`

```
void DoSomethingWith(ref int arg)
{
    arg++;
}

DoSomethingWith(ref x);
```

Then I'm giving that method control over my variable, `x`. If it adds 1 to `arg` then it's also adding 1 to `x`.

It's a tiny bit more confusing with reference types because whether you use `ref` or not, a method can modify the state of an object. For example, if you pass a `List<object>` to a method, that method can add or remove items from the list whether or not you used `ref`.

But again, if you use `ref` then the method receives control over your variable. It can create a different `List<object>` and assign it to your variable. It can set your variable to `null`. If you don't use `ref` it can't do that.

If I call this method - without `ref` - and pass a list of strings

```
void DoSomethingWithList(List<string> list)
{
    list.Add("Hello!");
    list = new List<string>();
    list.Add("Goodbye!");
}
```

This will add "Hello!" to the list that I passed in. But when it creates a new `List<string>` that won't affect the variable that I passed to the method. That variable will still reference the same list, now with with string "Hello!" added to it.

But if it uses `ref`

```
void DoSomethingWithList(ref List<string> list)
{
    list.Add("Hello!");
    list = new List<string>();
    list.Add("Goodbye!");
}
```

then whatever variable I passed in will be replaced with the new list. When the method is done executing my variable will contain a new `List<string>` with the word "Goodbye!".

Here's a [blog post](http://scotthannen.org/blog/2016/03/29/dot-net-reference-types-for-absolute-beginners.html) with some more examples.

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) for `ref` explains this. But as with much documentation, it's more about being accurate than being easy to read and understand. Once you understand it this makes perfect sense, but I can see it being hard to understand if you don't already know it.

> The effect of passing by reference is that any change to the parameter
>   in the called method is reflected in the calling method. For example,
>   if the caller passes a local variable expression or an array element
>   access expression, and the called method replaces the object to which
>   the ref parameter refers, then the caller’s local variable or the
>   array element now refer to the new object.

Maybe it's just me, but I just don't think it's helpful if someone is looking for information on something like `ref` and a term like "array element
access expression" gets thrown in. Even though it's not rocket science, it adds one more little burden to someone trying to grasp a new concept.